# Error while creating a node with file attachment through custom PHP code

Tags: entities, files, nodes

I need to programmaticly create  a node in Drupal 7 i followed availible tutorials and came up with this code:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);


$md5 = md5(strtotime("now"));

$field_customer_name = 'NAthtn';
$field_customer_email = "something@gmail.com";
$field_downloads_count_left = '11';

$filename = 'file123.zip';
$filepath = 'sites/default/files/private/file123.zip';

// Create managed File object and associate with file field.
$file = new StdClass();
$file->uid = 1;
$file->uri = $filepath;
$file->filename = $filename;
$file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($file->uri);
$file->status = 1;  
$file = file_copy($file, 'public://', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'download';
node_object_prepare($node);

$node->title    = $md5;
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

$node->field_customer_name[$node->language][0]['value'] = $field_customer_name;
$node->field_customer_email[$node->language][0]['value'] = $field_customer_email;
$node->field_downloads_count_left[$node->language][0]['value'] = $field_downloads_count_left;
$node->field_file[$node->language][0]['value'] = (array)$file;

$path = $md5;
$node->path = array('alias' => $path);

node_save($node);
```

I am getting the following error in the log:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'fid' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {file_usage} (fid, module, type, id, count) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => file [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 51 [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1 ) in file_usage_add() (line 664 of /home/content/16/5470416/html/download/includes/file.inc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

`$node->field_file[$node->language][0]['value'] = (array)$file;`

with

`$node->field_file[$node->language][] = (array)$file;`

Also, add `$node->validated = TRUE;` before `node_save($node);`

Comment: +1 for the first bit, adding `$node->validated` is unnecessary though

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! :) i also had to add display property, or else it gave me other error...